# Automate snapshots in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snapshot

I found the thread [Automating Linux EBS snapshots backup and clean-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003409/automating-linux-ebs-snapshots-backup-and-clean-up#new-answer?newreg=581ad198c32e4c80803a40badcaa6e7d) which 
Sergey Romanov has given the step-by-step instruction. I tested it and works great. (Thanks, Surgey.)

The cron entry I used `* 23 * * * /usr/local/ec2/backup.php`

However have a problem with adding cron job (last step). Got the error `crond[478]: (CRON) bad command (/etc/crontab)`. To fix it, I added a username (root) after which the error did not appear.

The updated cron entry is `* 23 * * * root /usr/local/ec2/backup.php`

However, the job is still not running. Is there anything I did was wrong?

Thanks

Comment: please edit your question and show the cron entry you are attempting to enter in the crontab. Also, look in the syslog for any lines referencing that cron and include those.

Comment: The cron entry as suggested by Surgey is * 23 * * * /usr/local/ec2/backup.php

Comment: and what's in `syslog`? I'm sure the script is failing.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The cronjob ran today. There was no failure messages after I added the username. Wait for another day to see if everything works as expected.